# PMC to count if software prefetch hit L1 cache

Tags: x86-64, intel, performancecounter, memory-barriers, intel-pmu

I am trying to find a PMC (Performance Monitoring Counter) that will display the amount of times that a `prefetcht0` instruction hits L1 dcache (or misses).

***icelake-client: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1065G7 CPU @ 1.30GHz***

I am trying to make this fine grain i.e (note should include `lfence` around `prefetcht0`)

```
    xorl %ecx, %ecx
    rdpmc
    movl %eax, %edi
    prefetcht0 (%rsi)
    rdpmc
    testl %eax, %edi
    // jump depending on if it was a miss or not
```

The goal is to check if a prefetch hit L1. If didn't execute some code that is ready, otherwise proceed.

It seems that it will have to be a miss event just based on what is available.

I have tried a few events [from libpfm4](https://github.com/wcohen/libpfm4) and intel manual with no luck:

```
L1-DCACHE-LOAD-MISSES, emask=0x00, umask=0x10000
L1D.REPLACEMENT, emask=0x51, umask=0x1 
L2_RQSTS.SWPF_HIT, emask=0x24, umask=0xc8
L2_RQSTS.SWPF_MISS, emask=0x24, umask=0x28
LOAD_HIT_PREFETCH.SWPF, emask=0x01, umask=0x4c  (this very misleadingly is non-sw prefetch hits)
```

`L1D.REPLACEMENT` and `L1-DCACHE-LOAD-MISSES` kind of works, it works if I delay the `rdpmc` but if they are one after another it seems unreliable at best. The other ones are complete busts.

Questions:

1. Should any of these work for detecting if prefetches hit L1 dcache? (i.e my testing is bad)
2. If not. Whats events could be used to detect if a prefetch hit L1 dcache?

Edit: `MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.L1_HIT` does not appear to work for software prefetch.

Here is the code I am using to do test:

```
#include <asm/unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/perf_event.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>


#define HIT  0
#define MISS 1

#define TODO MISS


#define PAGE_SIZE 4096

// to force hit make TSIZE low
#define TSIZE     10000

#define err_assert(cond)                                                       \
    if (__builtin_expect(!(cond), 0)) {                                        \
        fprintf(stderr, "%d:%d: %s\n", __LINE__, errno, strerror(errno));      \
        exit(-1);                                                              \
    }


uint64_t
get_addr() {
    uint8_t * addr =
        (uint8_t *)mmap(NULL, TSIZE * PAGE_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                        MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    err_assert(addr != NULL);


    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < TSIZE; ++i) {
        addr[i * PAGE_SIZE + (PAGE_SIZE - 1)] = 0;
        #if TODO == HIT
        addr[i * PAGE_SIZE] = 0;
        #endif
    }

    return uint64_t(addr);
}

int
perf_event_open(struct perf_event_attr * hw_event,
                pid_t                    pid,
                int                      cpu,
                int                      group_fd,
                unsigned long            flags) {
    int ret;

    ret = syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, hw_event, pid, cpu, group_fd, flags);
    return ret;
}

void
init_perf_event_struct(struct perf_event_attr * pe,
                       const uint32_t           type,
                       const uint64_t           ev_config,
                       int                      lead) {
    __builtin_memset(pe, 0, sizeof(struct perf_event_attr));

    pe->type           = type;
    pe->size           = sizeof(struct perf_event_attr);
    pe->config         = ev_config;
    pe->disabled       = !!lead;
    pe->exclude_kernel = 1;
    pe->exclude_hv     = 1;
}


/* Fixed Counters */
static constexpr uint32_t core_instruction_ev  = 0x003c;
static constexpr uint32_t core_instruction_idx = (1 << 30) + 0;

static constexpr uint32_t core_cycles_ev  = 0x00c0;
static constexpr uint32_t core_cycles_idx = (1 << 30) + 1;

static constexpr uint32_t ref_cycles_ev  = 0x0300;
static constexpr uint32_t ref_cycles_idx = (1 << 30) + 2;

/* programmable counters */
static constexpr uint32_t mem_load_retired_l1_hit  = 0x01d1;
static constexpr uint32_t mem_load_retired_l1_miss = 0x08d1;


int
init_perf_tracking() {
    struct perf_event_attr pe;

    init_perf_event_struct(&pe, PERF_TYPE_RAW, core_instruction_ev, 1);
    int leadfd = perf_event_open(&pe, 0, -1, -1, 0);
    err_assert(leadfd >= 0);

    init_perf_event_struct(&pe, PERF_TYPE_RAW, core_cycles_ev, 0);
    err_assert(perf_event_open(&pe, 0, -1, leadfd, 0) >= 0);

    init_perf_event_struct(&pe, PERF_TYPE_RAW, ref_cycles_ev, 0);
    err_assert(perf_event_open(&pe, 0, -1, leadfd, 0) >= 0);


    init_perf_event_struct(&pe, PERF_TYPE_RAW, mem_load_retired_l1_hit, 0);
    err_assert(perf_event_open(&pe, 0, -1, leadfd, 0) >= 0);

    return leadfd;
}

void
start_perf_tracking(int leadfd) {
    ioctl(leadfd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, 0);
    ioctl(leadfd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, 0);
}

#define _V_TO_STR(X) #X
#define V_TO_STR(X)  _V_TO_STR(X)

//#define DO_PREFETCH
#ifdef DO_PREFETCH
#define DO_MEMORY_OP(addr) "prefetcht0 (%[" V_TO_STR(addr) "])\n\t"
#else
#define DO_MEMORY_OP(addr) "movl (%[" V_TO_STR(addr) "]), %%eax\n\t"
#endif


int
main() {
    int fd = init_perf_tracking();
    start_perf_tracking(fd);

    uint64_t addr = get_addr();

    uint32_t prefetch_miss, cycles_to_detect;
    asm volatile(
        "lfence\n\t"
        "movl %[core_cycles_idx], %%ecx\n\t"
        "rdpmc\n\t"
        "movl %%eax, %[cycles_to_detect]\n\t"
        "xorl %%ecx, %%ecx\n\t"
        "rdpmc\n\t"
        "movl %%eax, %[prefetch_miss]\n\t"
        "lfence\n\t"
        DO_MEMORY_OP(prefetch_addr)
        "lfence\n\t"
        "xorl %%ecx, %%ecx\n\t"
        "rdpmc\n\t"
        "subl %[prefetch_miss], %%eax\n\t"
        "movl %%eax, %[prefetch_miss]\n\t"
        "movl %[core_cycles_idx], %%ecx\n\t"
        "rdpmc\n\t"
        "subl %[cycles_to_detect], %%eax\n\t"
        "movl %%eax, %[cycles_to_detect]\n\t"
        "lfence\n\t"
        : [ prefetch_miss ] "=&r"(prefetch_miss),
          [ cycles_to_detect ] "=&r"(cycles_to_detect)
        : [ prefetch_addr ] "r"(addr), [ core_cycles_idx ] "i"(core_cycles_idx)
        : "eax", "edx", "ecx");

    fprintf(stderr, "Hit    : %d\n", prefetch_miss);
    fprintf(stderr, "Cycles : %d\n", cycles_to_detect);
}
```

if I define `DO_PREFETCH` the results for `MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.L1_HIT` are always 1 (always appears to get a hit). If I comment out `DO_PREFETCH` the results correspond with what I would expect (when the address is clearly not in cache reports miss, when it clearly is reports hit).

With `DO_PREFETCH`:

```
g++ -DDO_PREFETCH -O3 -march=native -mtune=native prefetch_hits.cc -o prefetch_hits
$> ./prefetch_hits
Hit    : 1
Cycles : 554
```

and without `DO_PREFETCH`

```
g++ -DDO_PREFETCH -O3 -march=native -mtune=native prefetch_hits.cc -o prefetch_hits
$> ./prefetch_hits
Hit    : 0
Cycles : 888
```

With `L2_RQSTS.SWPF_HIT` and `L2_RQSTS.SWPF_MISS` was able to get it to work. Big thanks to Hadi Brais. Worth noting that the reason `L1D_PEND_MISS.PENDING` didn't work might be related to Icelake. Hadi Brais reported getting it to work for predicting L1D cached misses on Haswell.

In the interest of trying to determine why `L1_PEND_MISS.PENDING` and `MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.L1_HIT` do not work posted the exact code I'm using for testing them:

```
#include <asm/unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/perf_event.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>


#define HIT  0
#define MISS 1

#define TODO MISS


#define PAGE_SIZE 4096

#define TSIZE 1000

#define err_assert(cond)                                                       \
    if (__builtin_expect(!(cond), 0)) {                                        \
        fprintf(stderr, "%d:%d: %s\n", __LINE__, errno, strerror(errno));      \
        exit(-1);                                                              \
    }


uint64_t
get_addr() {
    uint8_t * addr =
        (uint8_t *)mmap(NULL, TSIZE * PAGE_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                        MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    err_assert(addr != NULL);
    __builtin_memset(addr, -1, TSIZE * PAGE_SIZE);
    return uint64_t(addr);
}

int
perf_event_open(struct perf_event_attr * hw_event,
                pid_t                    pid,
                int                      cpu,
                int                      group_fd,
                unsigned long            flags) {
    int ret;

    ret = syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, hw_event, pid, cpu, group_fd, flags);
    return ret;
}

void
init_perf_event_struct(struct perf_event_attr * pe,
                       const uint32_t           type,
                       const uint64_t           ev_config,
                       int                      lead) {
    __builtin_memset(pe, 0, sizeof(struct perf_event_attr));

    pe->type           = type;
    pe->size           = sizeof(struct perf_event_attr);
    pe->config         = ev_config;
    pe->disabled       = !!lead;
    pe->exclude_kernel = 1;
    pe->exclude_hv     = 1;
}


/* Fixed Counters */
static constexpr uint32_t core_instruction_ev  = 0x003c;
static constexpr uint32_t core_instruction_idx = (1 << 30) + 0;

static constexpr uint32_t core_cycles_ev  = 0x00c0;
static constexpr uint32_t core_cycles_idx = (1 << 30) + 1;

static constexpr uint32_t ref_cycles_ev  = 0x0300;
static constexpr uint32_t ref_cycles_idx = (1 << 30) + 2;

/* programmable counters */
static constexpr uint32_t mem_load_retired_l1_hit  = 0x01d1;
static constexpr uint32_t mem_load_retired_l1_miss = 0x08d1;
static constexpr uint32_t l1d_pending              = 0x0148;
static constexpr uint32_t swpf_hit                 = 0xc824;
static constexpr uint32_t swpf_miss                = 0x2824;
static constexpr uint32_t ev0                      = l1d_pending;

#define NEVENTS 1
#if NEVENTS > 1
static constexpr uint32_t ev1 = swpf_miss;
#endif

int
init_perf_tracking() {
    struct perf_event_attr pe;

    init_perf_event_struct(&pe, PERF_TYPE_RAW, core_instruction_ev, 1);
    int leadfd = perf_event_open(&pe, 0, -1, -1, 0);
    err_assert(leadfd >= 0);

    init_perf_event_struct(&pe, PERF_TYPE_RAW, core_cycles_ev, 0);
    err_assert(perf_event_open(&pe, 0, -1, leadfd, 0) >= 0);

    init_perf_event_struct(&pe, PERF_TYPE_RAW, ref_cycles_ev, 0);
    err_assert(perf_event_open(&pe, 0, -1, leadfd, 0) >= 0);

    init_perf_event_struct(&pe, PERF_TYPE_RAW, ev0, 0);
    err_assert(perf_event_open(&pe, 0, -1, leadfd, 0) >= 0);

#if NEVENTS > 1
    init_perf_event_struct(&pe, PERF_TYPE_RAW, ev1, 0);
    err_assert(perf_event_open(&pe, 0, -1, leadfd, 0) >= 0);
#endif

    return leadfd;
}

void
start_perf_tracking(int leadfd) {
    ioctl(leadfd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, 0);
    ioctl(leadfd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, 0);
}

#define _V_TO_STR(X) #X
#define V_TO_STR(X)  _V_TO_STR(X)

//#define LFENCE
#ifdef LFENCE
#define SERIALIZER() "lfence\n\t"
#else
#define SERIALIZER()                                                           \
    "xorl %%ecx, %%ecx\n\t"                                                    \
    "xorl %%eax, %%eax\n\t"                                                    \
    "cpuid\n\t"

#endif

#define DO_PREFETCH

#ifdef DO_PREFETCH
#define DO_MEMORY_OP(addr) "prefetcht0 (%[" V_TO_STR(addr) "])\n\t"
#else
#define DO_MEMORY_OP(addr) "movl (%[" V_TO_STR(addr) "]), %%eax\n\t"
#endif


int
main() {
    int fd = init_perf_tracking();
    start_perf_tracking(fd);

    uint64_t addr = get_addr();

    // to ensure page in TLB
    *((volatile uint64_t *)(addr + (PAGE_SIZE - 8))) = 0;
    
#if TODO == HIT
    // loading from 0 offset to check cache miss / hit
    *((volatile uint64_t *)addr) = 0;
#endif

    uint32_t ecount0 = 0, ecount1 = 0, cycles_to_detect = 0;
    asm volatile(
        SERIALIZER()
        "movl %[core_cycles_idx], %%ecx\n\t"
        "rdpmc\n\t"
        "movl %%eax, %[cycles_to_detect]\n\t"
        "xorl %%ecx, %%ecx\n\t"
        "rdpmc\n\t"
        "movl %%eax, %[ecount0]\n\t"
#if NEVENTS > 1
        "movl $1, %%ecx\n\t"
        "rdpmc\n\t"
        "movl %%eax, %[ecount1]\n\t"
#endif
        SERIALIZER()
        DO_MEMORY_OP(prefetch_addr)
        SERIALIZER()
        "xorl %%ecx, %%ecx\n\t"
        "rdpmc\n\t"
        "subl %[ecount0], %%eax\n\t"
        "movl %%eax, %[ecount0]\n\t"
#if NEVENTS > 1
        "movl $1, %%ecx\n\t"
        "rdpmc\n\t"
        "subl %[ecount1], %%eax\n\t"
        "movl %%eax, %[ecount1]\n\t"
#endif
        "movl %[core_cycles_idx], %%ecx\n\t"
        "rdpmc\n\t"
        "subl %[cycles_to_detect], %%eax\n\t"
        "movl %%eax, %[cycles_to_detect]\n\t"
        SERIALIZER()
        : [ ecount0 ] "=&r"(ecount0),
#if NEVENTS > 1
          [ ecount1 ] "=&r"(ecount1),
#endif
          [ cycles_to_detect ] "=&r"(cycles_to_detect)
        : [ prefetch_addr ] "r"(addr), [ core_cycles_idx ] "i"(core_cycles_idx)
        : "eax", "edx", "ecx");

    fprintf(stderr, "E0     : %d\n", ecount0);
    fprintf(stderr, "E1     : %d\n", ecount1);
    fprintf(stderr, "Cycles : %d\n", cycles_to_detect);
}
```

Comment: This isn't asking for a recommendation for a book, tool or library.  It's asking what hardware feature and algorithm, if any, can accomplish a specific task.  I don't think it should be closed.

Comment: slightly editted the question so it sounds less like asking for a suggestion, more like asking for an answer to a generic question.

Comment: Are you intending this as a profiling measure?  Or actually as an efficiency optimization, with the idea that if the prefetch didn't hit, the program can do some other work before actually trying the load?  The latter doesn't seem like the intended purpose of PMCs, and I would be interested whether experts think this approach makes sense at all.

Comment: @NateEldredge I am interested in using it for an optimization. I know its not the intended purpose but seems like its worth a try at least. I too am interested to see if this idea has any weight.

Comment: I'd tend to assume that the normal way to achieve this would be to structure your code so that out-of-order execution can run your "other work" while waiting for the load to complete, not to actually change the execution path.  But that assumes the "other work" eventually needs to be done in any case, which maybe is not true if you just want to spend otherwise idle time doing something that's optional (fold some proteins, etc).

Comment: @NateEldredge normally thats the case. My end use case for this is something along the lines of [nanocoroutines](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j9tlJAqMV7U). The idea would be instead of just blindly prefetching then switching execution you could check if is a miss first because the overhead of switching out the frame is not insignificant. For most code though I tend to agree.

Comment: I have not checked this on the IceLake processors, but what you are trying to do is unlikely to be useful for a number of reasons....  The RDPMC instruction is expensive -- the fastest implementation I have seen requires ~25 cycles, so your overhead is 50 cycles plus a likely branch misprediction.  Not quite a full memory latency, but certainly a big chunk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rdpmc` is not ordered with the events that may occur before it or after it in program order. A fully serializing instruction, such as `cpuid`, is required to obtain the desired ordering guarantees with respect to `prefetcht0`. The code should be as follows:

```
xor  %eax, %eax         # CPUID leaf eax=0 should be fast.  Doing this before each CPUID might be a good idea, but omitted for clarity
cpuid
xorl %ecx, %ecx
rdpmc
movl %eax, %edi         # save RDPMC result before CPUID overwrites EAX..EDX
cpuid
prefetcht0 (%rsi)
cpuid
xorl %ecx, %ecx
rdpmc
testl %eax, %edi        # CPUID doesn't affect FLAGS
cpuid
```

Each of the `rdpmc` instructions are sandwiched between `cpuid` instructions. This ensures that any events and only these events that occur between the two `rdpmc` instructions are counted.

The prefetch operation of the `prefetcht0` instruction may either be ignored or performed. If it was performed, it may either hit in a cache line that is in a valid state in the L1D or not. These are the cases that have to be considered.

The sum of `L2_RQSTS.SWPF_HIT` and `L2_RQSTS.SWPF_MISS` cannot be used to count or derive the number of `prefetcht0` hits in the L1D, but their sum can be subtracted from `SW_PREFETCH_ACCESS.T0` to get an upper bound on the number of `prefetcht0` hits in the L1D. With the properly serialized sequence shown above, I think the only case where a non-ignored `prefetcht0` doesn't hit in the L1D and is not counted by the sum `SWPF_HIT`+`SWPF_MISS` is if the software prefetch operation hits in an LFB allocated for a hardware prefetch.

`L1-DCACHE-LOAD-MISSES` is just another name for `L1D.REPLACEMENT`. The event code and umask you've shown for `L1-DCACHE-LOAD-MISSES` is incorrect. The `L1D.REPLACEMENT` event only occurs if the prefetch operation misses in the L1D (which causes a request to be sent to the L2) and causes a valid line in the L1D to be replaced. Usually most fills cause a replacement, but the event still cannot be used to distinguish between a `prefetcht0` that hits in the L1D, a `prefetcht0` that hits in an LFB allocated for a hardware prefetch, and an ignored `prefetcht0`.

The event `LOAD_HIT_PREFETCH.SWPF` occurs when a demand load hits in an LFB allocated for a software prefetch. This is obviously not useful here.

The event `L1D_PEND_MISS.PENDING` (event=0x48, umask=0x01) should work. According to the documentation, this event increments the counter by the number of pending L1D misses every cycle. I think it works for demand loads and prefetches. This is really an approximation, so it may count even if there are zero pending L1D misses. But I think it can still be used to determine with very high confidence whether a single `prefetcht0` missed in the L1D by following these steps:

- First, add the line `uint64_t value = *(volatile uint64_t*)addr;` just before the inline assembly. This is to increase the probability to near 100% that the line to be prefetched is in the L1D.
- Second, measure the minimum increment of `L1D_PEND_MISS.PENDING` for a `prefetcht0` that is very highly likely to hit in the L1D.
- Run the experiment many times to build high confidence that the minimum increment is highly stable to the extent the the same exact value is observed in almost every run.
- Comment out the line added in the first step so that the `prefetcht0` misses and check that the event count change is always or almost always larger than the minimum increment measured previously.

So far, I've only been concerned with making a distinction between a prefetch that hits in the L1D and a non-ignored prefetch that misses in both the L1D and the LFBs. Now I'll consider the rest of the cases:

- If the prefetch results in a page fault or if the memory type of the target cache line is WC or UC, the prefetch is ignored. I don't know whether the `L1D_PEND_MISS.PENDING` event can be used to distinguish between a hit and this case. You can run experiment where the target address of the prefetch instruction to is in a virtual page with no valid mapping or mapped to a kernel page. Check if the change in the event count is unique with high probability.
- If no LFBs are available, the prefetch is ignored. This case can be eliminated by switching off the sibling logical core and using `cpuid` instead of `lfence` before the first `rdpmc`.
- If the prefetch hits in an LFB allocated for an RFO, ItoM, or a hardware prefetch request, then the prefetch is effectively redundant. For all of these types of requests, the change in the `L1D_PEND_MISS.PENDING` count may or not be distinguishable from a hit in the L1D. This case can be eliminated by using `cpuid` instead of `lfence` before the first `rdpmc` and turning of the two L1D hardware prefetchers.
- I don't think a prefetch to a prefetchable memory type can hit in a WCB because changing the memory type of a location is a fully serializing operation, so this case is not a problem.

One obvious advantage of using `L1D_PEND_MISS.PENDING` instead of the sum `SWPF_HIT`+`SWPF_MISS` is the smaller number of events. Another advantage is that `L1D_PEND_MISS.PENDING` is supported on some of the earlier the microarchitectures. Also, as discussed above, it can be more powerful. It works on my Haswell with a threshold of 69-70 cycles.

If the `L1D_PEND_MISS.PENDING` event changes in different cases are not distinguishable, then the sum `SWPF_HIT`+`SWPF_MISS` can be used. These two events occur at the L2 and so they only tell you whether the prefetch missed in the L1D and a request is sent and accepted by the L2. If the request is rejected or hit in the L2's SQ, none of the two events may occur. In addition, all of the aforementioned cases will not be distinguishable from an L1D hit.

For normal demand loads, you can use `MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.L1_HIT`. If the load hits in the L1D, a single `L1_HIT` occurs. Otherwise, in any other case, no `L1_HIT` events occur, assuming that no other instruction between the two `rdpmc`s, such as `cpuid`, can generate `L1_HIT` events. You'll have to verify that `cpuid` doesn't generate `L1_HIT` events.  Don't forget to count only user-mode events because an interrupt can occur between any two instructions and the interrupt handler may generate one or more `L1_HIT` events in kernel mode. While it's very unlikely, if you want to be 100% sure, check also whether the occurrence of an interrupt itself generates `L1_HIT` events.

Comment: Serializing instruction execution with `lfence` isn't sufficient here?  You also need to drain the store buffer and whatever else with `cpuid`?

Comment: @PeterCordes It depends on the instructions in the region of interest. In this case, `prefetcht0` is only order by fully serializing instructions and not `lfence`or any other partially serializing instruction. It also matters here whether the SB is flushed or not because an earlier store may retire but still has an outstanding request with an LFB allocated at the time the prefetch is executed, so a hit in that same LFB may occur if it happens that they are to the same line. If the SB is flushed, such a store would bring the line in the L1D and the prefetch hits in the L1D instead.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if `lfence` in practice is sufficient on real hardware to order `prefetcht0` at least enough for L1 hit or not determination.  But interesting point about a cache-miss store waiting for the line to arrive.  However, the OP might *want* to detect cases where un-instrumented code would see an L1 miss from the prefetch, even though the prefetch would be near useless unless it runs significantly before the RFO goes out.  Anyway, probably not worth over-complicating your answer with this.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah I agree in practice on existing processors both `rdpmc` instructions could be sandwiched by `lfence` instead of `cpuid` (assuming you don't want to order stores)  but I felt like going by the manual here.

Comment: @PeterCordes I was thinking for this purpose I would also need a ```lfence``` before the first ``rdpmc``` so it wasnt reorded with any other loads that might hit L1 dcache and potentially give a false positive on the ```prefetcht0```. is that unnecissary?

Comment: @Noah: Hadi's example code has CPUID (fully serializing) before the first RDPMC and after the last RDPMC.  You might relax that to just an LFENCE, especially after some testing on the CPU you want to measure on to see how it behaves.  But there's no need for even more barriers than CPUID.

Comment: It looks like the code forgot about CPUID overwriting EAX..EDX though.  `movl %eax, %edi` after CPUID is weird; I think we want the RDPMC result, not the CPUID.  Also of the xor-zeroing needs to be done before RDPMC.  (Selecting a known CPUID leaf is a good idea to keep the speed consistent.)

Comment: @HadiBrais I tried ```MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.L1_HIT```. It seems to report hit for prefetch every time. It works fine for a true load from the address, however. Any ideas? I posted the code I am using for testing.

Comment: @Noah Right. The documentation does say that `L1_HIT` occurs for any software prefetches and I've also documented this elsewhere for other microarchitectures. But I forgot about this, sorry. I've updated the answer to suggest a different approach. I don't think there is an easy way to do this.

Comment: @HadiBrais still no luck with SW prefetch but working exactly as expected with a true load. Really suprising because the documenation on ```MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.L1_HIT``` and ```L1D_PEND_MISS.PENDING``` pretty explicitly includes SW prefetch. Changed serialized to ```cpuid``` but didn't change anything. Cest la vie.

Comment: @ Using `L1D_PEND_MISS.PENDING` works fine on my Haswell. Anyway, one more approach you can try is using the sum of the two events SWPF_HIT+SWPF_MISS. See the update to my answer.

Comment: @HadiBrais so ```L2_RQSTS.SWPF_HIT``` + ```L2_RQSTS.SWPF_MISS``` works! Awsome thank you! I am still unsure why ```L1D_PEND_MISS.PENDING``` and ```MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.L1_HIT``` don't work for me. Could you post the code you can ```L1D_PEND_MISS.PENDING``` to work with? Want to see what I'm messing up

Comment: @Noah Regarding `MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.L1_HIT`, the documentation says `This event includes all SW prefetches and lock instructions regardless of the data source.` It clearly says that software prefetches are counted regardless of whether they hit in the L1D or whatever happens. Regarding, `L1D_PEND_MISS.PENDING` I used your code and followed the exact steps mentioned in my answer. It's possible that the way this event is counted has changed on Ice Lake. What values are you getting in the second step? Are they zeroes or something else? In the fourth step, are you sure the prefetch misses?

Comment: @HadiBrais for ```L1D_PEND_MISS.PENDING``` I am getting 0 for both hits and misses. The only case I don't get 0 with a SW prefetch is when I get a DTLB miss. I would have figured it was a bug in the code but with standard load I get expected results.  with ```MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.L1_HIT``` I get report of hit for both hits and misses with SW prefetch. Again standard load gives expected results. Moved the load up to right before the inline asm.

Comment: @HadiBrais also since you are getting expected results with my code might be something with icelake. (but i'm probably more inclined to make a mistake than intel). The ```L2_RQSTS.SWPF_HIT``` + ```L2_RQSTS.SWPF_MISS``` is working exactly as expected though. Adds about ~10 cycles but compared to the serialization its not much.

Comment: @Noah On a DTLB miss, the page walker does go through the same path as a normal load (meaning through the L1D) and the documentation does say that `L1D_PEND_MISS.PENDING` is incremented for page walker accesses, but it's not clear for software and hardware prefetches. I don't think you've any mistake. This is also not a bug in Ice Lake. It's just that the way the event works has changed a little bit. Most events are not architectural and Intel can change their exact meaning in different processors.

Comment: @HadiBrais added the exact code I'm using for testing (using ```cpuid``` for serializing and store right before the asm). ```#define TODO``` can be ```MISS``` or ```HIT```. ```#define DO_PREFETCH``` uncommened will run it will prefetch, otherwise it will run it will a demand load. ```ev0``` can be set to any event to track for example ```l1d_pending``` for ```L1D_PEND_MISS.PENDING``` or ```MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.L1_HIT```.

Comment: @HadiBrais I see. Although in the manual right now (under the icelake section) the wording for ```L1D_PEND_MISS.PENDING``` and ```MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.L1_HIT``` SW prefetches are explicitly allowed. Strange. Thank you a ton for all the help! on your haswell machine you said you got ```L1D_PEND_MISS.PENDING``` to work. Did you get ```MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.L1_HIT``` to work?